# Load factor in HashMap with linkedList

Tags: hashmap, load-factor

For load factor, I know it's the total number of elements divided by the space available. For the picture below, at index 2 for example, does it count as 1 spot or 6?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for load factor, I know it's the total number of elements divide by the space available

Yes, the load factor is the total number of entries divided by the number of bins. That's the average number of entries stored in each bin of the `HashMap`. This number should be kept small in order for the `HashMap` to have expected constant running time for the `get(key)` and `put(key,value)` methods.

> at index 2 for example, does it count as 1 spot or 6

Each index represents 1 bin of the `HashMap`, regardless of how many entries are stored in it.

Therefore, in your example (the image you linked to), you have 10 entries and 5 bins, and the load factor is 2.